# Can QObject be made callable from Java Script

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

Is it possible to make QObject callable from Java Script?
What I mean is to register QObject derived class instance like this:

```
QObject* obj = new MyObject();
QJSValue js_value = js_engine.newQObject(obj);

js_engine.globalObject().setProperty("myFunction", js_value);
```

and then to be able to call **myFunction** from Java Script

```
myFunction()
```

Environment: Qt 5.0.1

Edit: Main purpose of this manipulation is to register C++ function or functor in Java Script engine and to make it available not as an object's property but as a standalone function.

Comment: What do you mean by `make QObject callable`? Making its member functions accessible? Based on your tag list: are you trying to access one of your C++ objects from JavaScript inside QML property bindings?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943554/how-to-get-javascript-in-a-qwebview-to-create-new-instances-of-c-based-classes

Comment: And Qt provides a good example: http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2/qt4/webkit-imageanalyzer.html

Comment: axxel, what I mean under callable is when QJSValue::isCallable() returns true. In its turn it means that the object can be called from JS. Not just one of it's methods, but the object itself.

Comment: Min Lin, no it's not the same.

Comment: @Maxym, can you show an example in C++ how do you want to call `obj` itself?

Comment: @Alexander Stepaniuk, I want to call it from Java Script, not C++. But in C++ it would look like js_value.call(..).

Comment: @Maxym, C++ object can't be called itself. Neither in C++ nor in JS. A  method can be called. It seems to me you want to call some method of `obj` class. As axxel mentioned before.

Comment: @Alexander Stepaniuk, ok, I also didn't find how to do that. I was doubting that it's not possible because then I's sort of impossible to export single function(or functor) from C++ to Java Script only an object with methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent too much time trying to do the same. And now I'm 99.9% sure there is no possibility to do that with current Qt build (5.0.1).

Comment: ok, looks like that. Thanks! Negative answer is also an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I dont think it is possible to add a function to the QJSEngine globalObject directly from C++. Although this trick works:

1. Define a QObject based class with the Q_INVOKABLE functions you want to expose to the QJSEngine.

   ```
   class MyObject : public QObject 
   {
       Q_OBJECT
   public:
       Q_INVOKABLE int myFunction(int x) 
       {
           return x + 3;
       }
   };
   ```
2. Create an instance of this object and define its parent from C++. (It is important that you define a parent for your object instance. Without a parent the QJSEngine will think it owns the object and could delete it!)

   ```
   MyObject *obj = new MyObject();
   obj->setParent(QCoreApplication::instance());
   ```
3. Expose your object to the QJSEngine.

   ```
   js_engine.globalObject().setProperty("myObject", js_engine.newQObject(obj));
   ```
4. Transfer your object's functions to the global object from JavaScript.

   ```
    engine.evaluate("this.myFunction = myObject.myFunction");
   ```
5. Remove myObject from the JavaScript environment.

   ```
    engine.evaluate("delete myObject");
   ```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Qt5, you can maybe use :

```
QObject* obj = new MyObject();
js_engine.globalObject().setProperty("myFunction", js_engine.toScriptValue(&obj::myFunction));
```

And you need that your QObject derived class has the `Q_OBJECT` macro and `Q_INVOKABLE` on each method that must be exposed.

If you are using QML, you should preferably use `QQmlContext::setContextObject` :

```
youQmlContext.setContextObject(new MyObject());
```

So all Q_PROPERTY, Q_INVOKABLE and Q_SLOT members of MyObject class will be available to QML/JS engine as members of the context itself.

Comment: What is &obj::myFunction? 'obj' is a pointer. Does this compile?

Comment: still, what do you mean under this? address of a member function? then I don't understand on which object will it be called.

Comment: forget about this, i thought we could register a member function from a class to the JsEngine, but only Qml Engine allows this.